# "delay()" Function not working not working in Dev cpp

Tags: c++, delay

I'm using Dev Cpp 5.11 and i'm trying to run a simple code with time delays but it gives me error that "delay()"is not defined.

Here's  my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dos.h> //for delay
#include <conio.h> //for getch()

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    clrscr();

    cout<<"3";
    delay(1000);
    cout<<"2";
    delay(1000);
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    delay(1000);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

My guess is that this is probably  a bug in dev cpp

Comment: Is there any reason you use such ancient headers? Modern C++ has all the funtions you need -> [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Answer (score 1):

`conio.h` & `dos.h` is not part of the C standard. You can use them in Borland compilers. Dev c++ is using GCC compiler.

Try this:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main(){
//Your code
Sleep(1000);
//Your code
return 0;
}
```